# Properties of non trivial zeroes of zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis

we know that for all the non trivial zeroes (denoted by $s$, where $s=x+iy$) of the zeta function

1. The zeroes are symmetrical about the real line $1/2$.
2. If $\Re(s)= (1/2-a)$ is a zero so is $\Re(s')=(1/2+a)$. [where $\Im(s)=\Im(s')=y$]
3. If $\Im(s)= (y)$ is a zero so is $\Im(s')=(-y)$. [where $\Re(s)=\Re(s')=x$]

Are there any other properties of Zeta function we are aware of? They can be conditionally dependent on the truth or falseness of zeta function too.

Comment: From the functional equation we know the vertical *density of zeros*. As well as upper bounds for those in $\Re(s) \ge \sigma > 1/2$ and lower bounds for those on $\Re(s)=1/2$. You can go further but the obtained properties of the zeros will be hardly usable and you'll encounter a lot of conjectures. The Lindelöf hypothesis is conjectured for every Dirichlet series with similar functional equation (for which the RH often fails) so its implication on the zeros is a major problem.

Comment: Thank you. So, as I understand from this statement ('obtained properties of the zeros will be hardly usable') other than these 3 properties (that relate non-trivial zeroes), we don't have any other similar relation (other than the statistical ones as you mentioned) regarding the non-trivial zeroes that follow directly from the two possible assumptions, namely: (1) R.H. is false (2) R.H. is true. ?

Comment: If the RH is false let $\sigma_0 =\sup_\rho \Re(\rho)$ then we don't know if $\sigma < 1$, in that case if $\sigma_0 = \Re(\rho)$ for some zero, and what is the density of zeros close to $\sigma_0$

Comment: I understand. But this is a statistical property and I understood your point regarding that. The property I was a asking was similar to the above 3: which relate to the form of the non trivial zeroes or an existential relationship (as above)..